# simple do/while loop infinite loop issue

Tags: javascript, loops, do-while

Okay first off, im very new to javascript and doing some tutorials to try and learn the language. My problem is probably something incredibly simple, but i can't figure it out!

Okay so ive made a very simple do/while loop. All this should do is print "do condition, only once" a single time to the console and print "do" 5 times to the console.

However it goes into an infinite loop.. probably because im defining the variable "doCondition" in the wrong place, but i cant figure out where else logically i should place it.

Any help gratefully recieved! If you could also explain where i went wrong too, i would really appreciate it.

Many thanks,

```
var doWhileLoop = function(text){
var doCondition = 5;
    do {
    console.log("do condition, once only");
};

while(doCondition > 0){
    console.log(text);
    doCondition--;
}
}

doWhileLoop("do");
```

Comment: what is `do` block?.. You want to achieve like this... http://jsfiddle.net/c5yhpav9/

Comment: Remove semi-colon just after do and try this syntax do{} while(condition)

Comment: That code won't run at all, because of the syntax error in the first loop. What does the actual code that you are using look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do.. while syntax is incorrect, in your case, it goes like

```js
var doWhileLoop = function(text) {
  var doCondition = 5;
  //beginning of loop
  do {
    console.log(text, doCondition);
    doCondition--;
  } while (doCondition > 0); //end of loop
};

doWhileLoop("do");
```

```html
open console....
```

**EDIT**

while loop body won't execute as condition fails

```js
var whileLoop = function(text) {
  var condition = 0;
  //beginning of loop
  while (condition > 0) {
    console.log(text, condition);
    condition--;
  } //end of loop
};

whileLoop("while");
```

```html
open console....
```

do while loop body will execute once even if condition fails

```js
var doWhileLoop = function(text) {
  var condition = 0;
  //beginning of loop
  do {
    console.log(text, condition);
    condition--;
  } while (condition > 0); //end of loop
};

doWhileLoop("do while");
```

```html
open console....
```

Comment: I might be misunderstanding do/while loops altogether but i thought they were used to run a do statement once separately to the while statement? So regardless of the while condition the do will run a single time?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Do while execute only once and next iterations will depend on while condition. Only problem here was do while syntax.

Comment: ah... i think ive got it. I was thinking the do statement would run completely separately to the while condition. So if i had a do/while statement with a while condition that limited it to 5 times, the statement would actually run 6 times, once for the do and 5 times for the while? Whereas the do will run once regardless of the while condition being met, but if it is met it will just run as a normal while?

Answer (score 0):

This is the difference between a pre-conditioned loop (`while(condition) {...}`) and a post-conditioned loop (`do{...}while(condition);`).

The main difference is that a post-conditioned loop will *always* run the code block *at least once* before evaluating the condition, whereas a pre-conditioned loop will first attempt to evaluate the condition before running its code block

In your examples you've forgotten the condition in your post-conditioned loop, so it loops for ever.

References:

- [`do...while` (post-conditioned loop)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while)
- [`while....` (pre-conditioned loop)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while)

Answer (score 0):

This is not because of variable doCondition. It is because you are writing your do-while wrong. Check this out.

```
  var doWhileLoop = function(text){

var doCondition = 5;
    do {
    console.log("do condition, once only");
    doCondition--;
}while(doCondition > 0)
}

doWhileLoop("do");
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have isn't a single loop, but two separate loops. A `do {} while()` loop and a `while() {}` loop only differ in whether the condition is evaluated before or after each iteration.

There is no initial "do once" step in a `do...while` loop. Just put the code that you want to execute once before the loop:

```
var doWhileLoop = function(text){
  var doCondition = 5;
  console.log("do condition, once only");
  do {
    console.log(text);
    doCondition--;
  while (doCondition > 0);
};

doWhileLoop("do");
```